# Exporting R Shiny App to a PDF file that I can save on my computer

Tags: pdf, shiny, export

I am wanting to export the below shiny app to a PDF file. The instructions I have received so far are not that helpful.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(extrafont)
library(shinyscreenshot)
library(DT)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggpubr)
library(tidyverse)
library(rmarkdown)
library(pagedown)
library(webshot)
library(summarytools)

# Load datasets

Player_Information \<- read.csv("C:/Users/zac.crang/OneDrive/Player and Club Information/Player_Information.csv")
Team_Information \<- read.csv("C:/Users/zac.crang/OneDrive/Player and Club Information/Team_Information.csv")

# Create a new column "Player Name"

Player_Information$PlayerName \<- paste(Player_Information$playerFirstName, Player_Information$playerLastName, sep = " ")

# Define UI

ui \<- fluidPage(
useShinyjs(),
selectInput("team", "Choose a team:", choices = unique(Team_Information$teamName),
selected = "Your Default Team"),

# Player Dropdowns - 1st Fluid

fluidRow(
lapply(1:17, function(i) {
column(2,
div(
selectInput(paste0("player", i), "Choose a player:", "")
)
)
})
), # Closing 1st Fluid Row

# Team Logo - 2nd Fluid

fluidRow(
column(11, offset = 1,
align = "center",
tags$div(
img(id = "teamLogo", alt = "Team Logo", width = 100, height = 100, style = "margin-top: 10px; float: right;"),
textOutput("teamInfoText"),
style = "font-size: 50px; font-family: 'Arial Black'; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top: 10px"  # Adjust font size and family as needed
)
)
), # Closing 2nd Fluid Row

## Their FB - 3rd Fluid

fluidRow(
column(12, align = "center",
h4("FB", align = "center", style = "font-size: 28px; font-family: 'Arial Black'")  # Title for the left group centered
)
), # Closing 3rd Fluid

# Fullback Image - 4th Fluid

fluidRow(
column(12,
align = "center",
img(id = paste0("headshot", 1), alt = "Player Headshot", width = 150, height = 100, style = "margin: 0; padding: 0;"),
div(textOutput(outputId = paste0("lastname", 1)), style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold")
)
), # Closing 4th Fluid

# Their RHS & LHS Labels - 5th Fluid

fluidRow(
column(6, align = "center",
h4("THEIR RHS", align = "center", style = "font-size: 28px; font-family: 'Arial Black'")  # Title for the left group centered
),
column(6, align = "center",
h4("THEIR LHS", align = "center", style = "font-size: 28px; font-family: 'Arial Black'") # Title for the right group centered
)
),  # Closing 5th Fluid

# Player Images 2 - 9 - 6th Fluid

fluidRow(
class = "d-flex justify-content-center", # Center the entire row

    column(6,
           style = "padding: 0", align = "center", # Add border and padding: 0 to the entire left group
           lapply(2:5, function(i) {
             column(3, offset = 1, 
                    style = "margin: 0; padding: 0", # Add border, margin: 0, and padding: 0 to each column in the left group
                    img(id = paste0("headshot", i), alt = "Player Headshot", width = 150, height = 100, style = "margin: 0; padding: 0"),
                    div(textOutput(outputId = paste0("lastname", i)), style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold")  # Use div tag for styling, add inline CSS for text-align
             )
           })
    ),
    
    column(6, 
           lapply(6:9, function(i) {
             column(3, 
                    style = "margin: 0; padding: 0", align = "center", # Add border, margin: 0, and padding: 0 to each column in the right group
                    img(id = paste0("headshot", i), alt = "Player Headshot", width = 150, height = 100, style = "margin: 0; padding: 0; border"),
                    div(textOutput(outputId = paste0("lastname", i)), style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold;")  # Use div tag for styling, add inline CSS for text-align
             )
           })
    )

), # Closing 6th Fluid

# Middle Title & Images - 7th Fluid

fluidRow(
column(12, align = "center",
h4("THEIR MID", align = "center", style = "font-size: 28px; font-family: 'Arial Black'")  # Title for the left group centered
),

    column(6, offset = 3, 
           style = "padding: 0;", align = "center", # Add padding: 0 to the entire right group
           lapply(10:13, function(i) {
             column(3, 
                    style = "margin: 0; padding: 0;", # Add margin: 0 and padding: 0 to each column in the right group
                    img(id = paste0("headshot", i), alt = "Player Headshot", width = 150, height = 100, style = "margin: 0; padding: 0;"),
                    div(textOutput(outputId = paste0("lastname", i)), style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold")  # Use div tag for styling, add inline CSS for text-align
             )
           })
    )

), # Closing 7th Fluid

# Blank Row - 8th Fluid

fluidRow(
column(12,
div(),
style = "height: 20px;"  # Adjust the height as needed
)
),

# Interchange Title & Images - 9th Fluid

fluidRow(
column(12, align = "center",
h4("THEIR INT", align = "center", style = "font-size: 28px; font-family: 'Arial Black'")
),

    column(6, offset = 3,  
           style = "padding: 0; background-color: #FFC001; padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px;", align = "center",  # Add border to the entire right group
           lapply(14:17, function(i) {
             column(3,
                    style = "margin: 0; padding: 0",  # Add border to each column in the right group
                    img(id = paste0("headshot", i), alt = "Player Headshot", width = 150, height = 100, style = "margin: 0; padding: 0"),
                    div(textOutput(outputId = paste0("lastname", i)), style = "text-align: center; font-weight: bold")  # Use div tag for styling, add inline CSS for text-align
             )
           })
    )

), # Closing 9th Fluid

downloadButton('export'),

# Hide/Show All Button

fluidRow(
column(12,
div(
actionButton("hideAllBtn", "Hide/Show All")
)
)
) # Closing for Hide Button
)

# Define server

server \<- function(input, output, session) {

## The element vals will store all images and text you want to export

vals \<- reactiveValues(
teamLogo = NULL,
teamInfoText = NULL,
playerHeadshots = rep(list(NULL), 17),
playerLastNames = rep(list(NULL), 17)
)

observe({
team_players \<- subset(Player_Information, teamName == input$team)

    lapply(1:17, function(i) {
      updateSelectInput(session, paste0("player", i), choices = unique(team_players$PlayerName))
    })

})

output$teamInfoText \<- renderText({
selected_team \<- input$team
team_info \<- subset(Team_Information, teamName == selected_team)
if (nrow(team_info) \> 0) {
shinyjs::runjs(sprintf('$("#teamInfoText").css("color", "%s");', team_info$teamHexColour))
shinyjs::runjs(sprintf('$("#teamLogo").attr("src", "%s");', team_info$teamLogoURL))
vals$teamLogo \<- team_info$teamLogoURL
vals$teamInfoText \<- paste(selected_team)
} else {
vals$teamInfoText \<- "No information available for the selected team."
}
})

observe({
lapply(1:17, function(i) {
selected_player \<- input\[\[paste0("player", i)\]\]
player_info \<- subset(Player_Information, PlayerName == selected_player)
shinyjs::runjs(sprintf('$("#headshot%s").attr("src", "%s");', i, player_info$playerHeadshotURL))
vals$playerHeadshots\[\[i\]\] \<- player_info$playerHeadshotURL
vals$playerLastNames\[\[i\]\] \<- player_info$playerLastName
})
})

output$export = downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
"exported_content.pdf"
},
content = function(file) {
pdf(file, onefile = TRUE, width = 15, height = 9)
\# Add the content you want to export to the PDF using vals
\# For example:
cat("Team Information:\\n", vals$teamInfoText, "\\n\\n", file = file, sep = "")
cat("Team Logo:\\n", vals$teamLogo, "\\n\\n", file = file, sep = "")
for (i in 1:17) {
cat(paste("Player Headshot", i, ":\\n", vals$playerHeadshots\[\[i\]\], "\\n\\n"), file = file, sep = "")
cat(paste("Player Last Name", i, ":\\n", vals$playerLastNames\[\[i\]\], "\\n\\n"), file = file, sep = "")
}
dev.off()
}
)
}

# Create Shiny App

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So far I have a "Download" button that when I click, it allows me to save a PDF file. However, when I go to open the file, it pops up with an error message "There was an error opening this document. The file can not be opened as it has no pages". Please help, as I have no clue what is going wrong and have used chat GPT to get to this point.